# Android webview detect network error of ajax request

Tags: android, webview

I show a page in my app with webview. I have set up a webclient where I override the method `onReceivedError()` to get error of webview, if there is no internet I show a custom page.

But how can I detect network failure once the page is loaded,and say user pressed a button,and a ajax request is being made, but the request fails because of network connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

try this following method to check whether the internet is available or not before calling web request.

```
public static boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

required permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: problem is i need to detect it on ajax request ,like when a user press a delete button on web,and the webpage requests a ajax call on server.